# Parameter is not valid- g Graphics

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graphics, parameters, system.drawing

I'm writing a game in c#, Visual Studio. The game is 'Space Invaders', and as you know I somehow need to do the darts, so my teacher told me to do that with chain and with class name Dart(GetX, GetY, SetX, SetY and also painting the dart itself). when I write my code in the play game form everything is right but the visual sending me a message that the parameter (g) is not valid and I have tried so many things and nothing is working.

I'm sorry if I said too much or did anything wrong, it's my first time asking here.
[The image is the Dart class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rntj.png)

```
public partial class PlayGame : Form
{
    Graphics g;
    SpaBoard sb;
    bool right;
    int countMove = 0;
    Lives life;
    int score= 0;
    int m = 0;
    int s = 0;
    Node<Dart> chain = null;

    public PlayGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void PlayGame_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        sb.PaintSpaBoard(g);
        if (chain == null)
            timer3.Stop();
        while (chain != null)
        {
            Node<Dart> p = chain;
            while (p != null)
            {
                p.GetValue().PaintDart(g);
                p = chain.GetNext();
            }
        }
    private void PlayGame_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        g = CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void PlayGame_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
      int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

     if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
     {
       x = x + 20;
       if (x >= 1800)
          x = 1800;
       Point p = new Point(x, y);
       pictureBox1.Location = p;
       pictureBox1.Refresh();

      }            
     if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
     {  
       x = x - 20;
       if (x <=  100)
         x = 100;
       Point p = new Point(x, y);
       pictureBox1.Location = p;
       pictureBox1.Refresh();
     }
     if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)
     {
       x = x + 75;
       Dart d = new Dart();
       d.SetX(x);
       d.SetY(y);              
       if (chain == null)
       {
         chain=new Node<Dart>(d);
       }
       else
       {
         chain.SetNext(new Node<Dart>(d));
       }              
       Dart p = chain.GetValue();
       p.PaintDart(g);
       timer3.Start();
      }

      private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        while (chain != null)
        {
          if (chain.GetValue().GetY() > 50)
          {
            chain.GetValue().SetY(chain.GetValue().GetY() - 10);
          }
          chain = chain.GetNext();
        }
        if (chain == null)
            timer3.Stop();
        }
```

//Class Dart

```
 class Dart
   {
    private int x;
    private int y;`

    public Dart() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public int GetX() { return this.x; }
    public void SetX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public int GetY() { return this.y; }
    public void SetY(int Y) { this.y = y; }

    public void PaintDart(Graphics g) {
        Image pic = Image.FromFile("Dart.png");
        Point p = new Point(this.x, this.y);
        g.DrawImage(pic, p);
    }
}
```

Comment: When does this error message occur? Could you also show the whole message exactly as it is?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and copy-and-paste the code as text. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: What argument are you passing to that function and from where? Also, `Set..` and `Get...` is not very C#-like. In C#, you have [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for that.

Comment: System.ArgumentException:'The parameter is not valid'.

Comment: Looks like you need to add the code that calls `PaintDart`.

Comment: Please show the entire method where the code `if (e.KeyData == Keys.Space)`,  That looks like it is in a `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` handler.  Where are you getting the `Graphics` instance?

Comment: It is not clear why you have a `Graphics g` variable at all, or that `PaintDart` method.  You should be doing all drawing in the `Paint` event which is provided a valid graphics object as an event arg

Comment: In `PlayGame_KeyDown`, where does `g` come from? If your answer is "from the `PlayGame_Paint` event handler", then you can't use the graphics object like this, it might not exist any more/yet at the time your KeyDown event is called.

Comment: What is chain and where is it declared?

Comment: What is Node and where is it declared? Or am I missing a using or reference?

Comment: The Node declared in her:                                                                                    
public partial class PlayGame : Form
    { Node<Dart>chain=null;}                                                                                                                          @Mary

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So from where g needs to come?

Comment: @Emily But what is Node?

Comment: @Mary I did Node in type Dart. - It's called chain

Comment: @Mary I mean, in my code it's called chain.

Comment: I don't see any Node in the Dart class. I don't see any chain declare either.

Comment: @Mary I edited the code.

Comment: You don't need to create new `Graphics` objects as you do in the `MouseClick` event. Use the `e.Graphics` instead and pass it to your classes. Remove the `g` class level variable, remove the `MosueClick` event, in the `playGame_Paint` event, use `sb.PaintSpaBoard(e.Graphics)` and `p.GetValue().PaintDart(e.Graphics);` instead. and call the `DrawingControl.Invalidate()` method whenever and wherever in your code when you need to refresh the drawing.

Comment: You don't want to load the bitmap every time you draw on the screen. Read the image in the class `Dart` initializer.

Answer (score 1):

You get the reference `g` to the `Graphics` object from the `OnPaint()` method of the form.

Here is a sample code that draws an image on the form using the paint event:

[image: scr]

```
public class Dart
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private readonly Image image;

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set {x=value;}
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set {y=value; }
    }

    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }
    }

    public Dart()
    {
        this.X = 0;
        this.Y = 0;
        this.image = Image.FromFile("Dart.png");
    }

    public void PaintDart(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawImage(image, x, y);
    }
}
```

and the form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Dart dart;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.dart = new Dart();
    }
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        this.Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        // center the origin to the form

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(ClientSize.Width/2, ClientSize.Height/2);

        dart.PaintDart(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```